# What does a Process VM actually do? Does this qualify?

Tags: c, assembly, process, cpu-registers, vm-implementation

I'm building a basic register based virtual machine which takes in a file which defines variables (and adds them to a symbol table as they are defined), then reads (line by line) different mnemonics and values, and  executes the instructions that they represent until the 'halt' instruction is reached. Does this fit the definition of a process virtual machine?I just want to make sure.

Comment: Take a look of [Process virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Process_virtual_machines) at Wikipedia.

Comment: This definitely qualifies as a process Virtual Machine.